# Cost Distance Paths in Python

Tags: arcpy, cost-path

I have a feature dataset with 317 points (UpperPoints) and another with 394 (LowerPoints) points. Now I want to calculate the cost paths as in this [example here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/85169/how-to-create-a-loop-for-multiple-points-with-cost-distance-cost-path-in-arcgi). However there are multiple files used and i just want to iterate trough my shapefiles. In the end I want the cost paths from every single UpperPoint to every single LowerPoint. I know that I have to calculate the cosDistance rasters for every lower Point which will need a lot of computation time, but that's not an issue. My main problem is how to extract the points from the shapefiles and iterate trough these to create the CostDistance rasters. I assume that my solution, just using the for loop is too simplistic...

```
PointsHIGH = "C:\\Dogon\\lcp.gdb\\Pts_rangeH_high"
PointsLOW = "C:\\Dogon\\lcp.gdb\\Pts_rangeH_low"
costsurface = ("C:\\Dogon\\lcp.gdb\\Slope_asc")

outputCostDist = "C:\\Dogon\\lcp.gdb\\CstDstLOW"
outputCostBackLink = "C:\\Dogon\\lcp.gdb\\BckLnkLOW"
outputCostPath = "C:\\Dogon\\lcp.gdb\\CostPath"

for points in PointsLOW
    outputCostDist = arcpy.gp.CostDistance_sa(points, costsurface, outputCostBackLink)
    outputCostPath = arcpy.gp.CostPath(points, outputCostDist, outputCostBackLink,"BEST_SINGLE")
```

Further I want an output of all CostDistance rasters and CostPaths, how could I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can loop on a selection of each point in a layer.

```
for i in range(int(arcpy.GetCount_management(PointsLOW).getOutput(0)):
    arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(PointsLOW, "point" + str(i), ' "OID" = ' + str(i)) 
    outputCostDist = arcpy.gp.CostDistance_sa("point" + str(i), costsurface + str(i), outputCostBackLink + str(i))
    outputCostDist.save("yourname" + str(i))
```

Comment: Ok, thanks. But then i would have to define every i-th output beforehand. How would you do that? inside the loop?

Comment: Not sure that I understand your comment. Note that in my example, str(i) makes sure that the all the names are different (would be nicer with .format(), but I thought that this would be easier to read ) . If you want specific names, you can build a list by hand, e.g.  names= ["name1", "name2", etc] then call each name from the list with names[i] . If you build this list with a loop, it is probably not necessary to use a list (you can create the names on the fly, Python is great for this).

Comment: Thanks, well i basically just want an output for every file that i create. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12560600/creating-a-new-file-filename-contains-loop-variable-python) does it to some extent. However I think I use another python version, it looks at the costsurface output as the input raster, but otherwise it looks good

Comment: I've added the line of code to save your rster as permanent. In the future, try to mention your ArcGIS version if you need exact code.