# Using the same backlink and cost-distance rasters for different source/destination points over the same geographic region

Tags: arcpy, spatial-analyst, cost-path

I am conducting a cost distance analysis for many points on the same map (roughly 350 sets of source/destination points, creating 350 different cost distance paths in total). The map is large, at approximately 3.0*10^5 km^2. I have created the cost surface for the geographic region, as well. All that needs to be done is to run the information in the Cost Distance tool with a loop via Arcpy. This task will be time consuming, though, and I am wondering if there are any "shortcuts" I can take to reduce computation time.

Since I am using the same map to conduct my cost-distance analysis, can I somehow use the same backlink and same cost distance rasters created with the first source/destination points for the remaining ~349 source/destination points, produce incorrect results?

Comment: Can you provide a code snippet that illustrates how you are currently doing this, please? Questions asking how to improve code should present code.

Comment: Unfortunately I have yet to implement any code but it will likely be similar to this post: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/95773/cost-distance-paths-in-python

Comment: That sounds like some starting code for your first cut so I think you should begin by testing it or something based on it.